Difference of participles between הוּכָן vs. נָכוֹן
There are several particples derived from the root כוּן. There are many usages of the niphal particple נָכוֹן, such as Shemos 19:15, Isaiah 2:2, Micah 4:1. It is translated as ready, prepared, correct, etc. The huphal particple הוּכָן is used in Isaiah 16:5, Isaiah 30:33, and Zechariah 5:11. It is translated  into English as prepared. Also there is a present form מוּכַן in Mishlei 21:31. What is a difference in usage of these particples?

How would you prefer to translate a causative passive?

You mean הוּכָן and נָכוֹן?

As one can see from the cases in Tanach, the particple הוּכָן places emphasis on the act of preparation, which will cause readiness. By contrast, the particple נָכוֹן signifies the final result of readiness irrespective of one's preparation.
Examples for הוּכָן:

Isaiah 16:5


And a throne shall be established (וְהוּכַ֤ן) in goodness in the tent of David, and on it shall sit in faithfulness a ruler devoted to justice and zealous for equity.

The focus is on the work of establishing the dynasty of David by acts of goodness, which we are supposed to do now.

Isaiah 30:33


The Topheth has long been ready for him; he too is destined (הוּכָ֖ן) for Melech — His firepit has been made both wide and deep, with plenty of fire and firewood, and with G-D’s breath burning in it like a stream of sulfur.

The verse is stating that Topheth, a site near Jerusalem at which human beings were sacrificed by fire in periods of paganizing, is being destined (prepared) for service of the idol Molech. And even so, at the end that will be the place where G-d will execute the judgement. The focus is on the preparation, i.e. on what people do now for this final judgement even if there are societal pressures for idol worship.

Zecharia 5:11


And he answered, “To build a shrine for it in the land of Shinar; [a stand] shall be erected (וְהוּכַ֛ן) for it, and it shall be set down there upon the stand.”

I.e. the focus is on erecting the stand.
Examples for נָכוֹן:

Shemos 19:15


And he said to the people, “Be ready (נְכֹנִ֖ים) for the third day: [the men among] you should not go near a woman.”

I.e. do what one needs to do, but at the end of the 3rd day make sure to be ready.

Isaiah 2:2


In the days to come, the Mount of  G-D’s House shall stand firm (נָכ֨וֹן) above the mountains and tower above the hills; and all the nations shall gaze on it with joy.

I.e. the Mountain of G-d will be set established to a degree that nobody will recall how it was getting established.

Micah 4:1


In the days to come, the Mount of  GOD’s House shall stand firm above the mountains; and it shall tower above the hills. The peoples shall gaze on it with joy.

Essentially the same verse as Isaiah 2:2.
